# Click event does not fire default action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

So, I have this `<ol>` with some events attached with the help of jQuery (1.4.2). All is done in the `$(document).ready()`-call.

The weird thing is that the click on the `<li>` does generate a click on the correnct `<a>` (I can see this by uncommenting the `console.log()`-part) but it does not navigate the UA. Why is this? Does `event.stopPropagation()` call `event.preventDefault()` internally or what?

I know I can do `window.location.href = $('h3 a', this).eq(0).attr('href');` in the click event of the `<li>` but I really would like to know why it´s not working with the click-call.

Thanks in advance fellow SOers!

Teh codez:

HTML:

```
<ol class="news">
    <li>
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/325x325/000/fff.jpg">
        <span class="date">12th of May</span>
        <h3><a href="http://example.com/lorem-ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</a></h3>
        <p>Nullam rhoncus, massa nec posuere rutrum, mauris metus ornare lacus, facilisis. Rhoncus purus dui vel lectus.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="date">3rd of May</span>
        <h3><a href="http://example.com/lam-sum-idum">Lam sum idum</a></h3>
        <p>Mauris volutpat enim nec turpis pharetra consectetur. Cras faucibus mattis dignissim.</p>
    </li>
    <!-- many more LIs here... -->
</ol>
```

(and yes. The HTML 4.01 has been validated.)

JavaScript:

```
$('.news li').click(function () {
    $('h3 a', this).eq(0).click();
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
}).find('h3 a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();// prevent recursion
    //console.log(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal, manually firing a `click` on an anchor does *not* follow the link, firing the "default event" is often not the case when simulating the action.  Setting the `location.href` is the way to go here, like this:

```
$('.news li').click(function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).find('h3 a').attr('href');
}).hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
}).find('h3 a').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); //so ctrl+click works on the link, etc
});
```

As an aside, there's no need for the `.eq(0)`, `.attr('href')` will get the `href` from the first element in the matched set.

Comment: +1, with a friendly reminder - this will not work for links that have the target attribute set :-)