# How to fire hyper link through jquery trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I want to fire hyper link through javascript. It link must be open in new tab.

We can use window.open('url') but we know browser blocks popup. So i need alternate solution for it.

I have tried with trigger() but it doesn't work.

My HTML code is :

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click to fire">
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

My script is :

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#link').trigger('click');
});
```

Besides i used click(), it doesn't work too.

Code is :

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#link').click();
});
```

Can you any one help me?

Comment: I had the same a couple of months ago. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802731/click-event-does-not-fire-default-action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is your solution - http://jsfiddle.net/svTWu/1/

Here is the code

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Click to fire">
<a class="thelink" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>

$(".thelink").click(function () {
  window.open($(this).attr("href"));console.log('hello');
});

$("#btn").click(function () {
  $(".thelink").trigger('click');
});
```

Here you can read all information about trigger - http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: Please include the code in your answer and explain why it solves the problem.